# How to unit test a method that is having multiple object creation in switch statement? How to Mock them?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, moq, solid-principles, separation-of-concerns

Another question is if there is any better way to write this method?

```
Public decimal CalculateTotalPrice(List<product> items)
{
    decimal totalPrice = 0.m;

    foreach(Product p in items)
    {
        if(p.Offer == "")
            calc = new DefaultCalc();
        else if(p.Offer == "BuyOneGetOneFree")
            calc = new BuyOneGetOneFreeCalc();
        else if(p.Offer == "ThreeInPriceOfTwo")
            calc = new ThreeInPriceOfTwoCalc()

        totalPrice += calc.Calculate(p.Quantity, p.UnitPrice);
    }
    return totalPrice;
}
```

Comment: concerning the switch, check out strategy pattern.

Comment: Just for the record: now that you reached upvote levels, you can show your appreciation for the accepted answer, but also all other helpful ones ... by simply upvoting them ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably review [Polly Want a Message](https://www.deconstructconf.com/2018/sandi-metz-polly-want-a-message), by Sandi Metz

> How to unit test a method that is having multiple object creation in switch statement?

An important thing to notice here is that the switch statement is an *implementation detail*.  From the point of view of the caller, this thing is just a function

```
Public decimal CalculateTotalPrice(List<product> items);
```

If the pricing computations are fixed, you can just use the usual example based tests:

```
assertEquals(expectedPrice, CalculateTotalPrice(items));
```

But if they aren't fixed, you can still do testing based on the properties of the method.  Scott Wlaschin has a really good [introduction to property based testing](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/pbt/).  Based on the logic you show here, there are some things we can promise about prices, without knowing anything about the strategies in use

- the price should always be greater than zero.
- the price of a list of items is the same as the sum of the prices of the individual items.

> if there is any better way to write this method?

You might separate *choosing* the pricing strategy from *using* the strategy.  As Sandi notes, that sort of construct often shows up in more than once place.

```
foreach(Product p in items)
{
    calc = pricing(p.Offer);
    totalPrice += calc.Calculate(p.Quantity, p.UnitPrice);
}
```

"pricing" would then become something that you pass into this function (either as an argument, or as a dependency).

In effect, you would end up with three different kinds of test.

- Checks that pricing returns the right pricing strategy for each offer.
- Checks that each strategy performs its own calculation correctly.
- Checks that `CalculateTotalPrice` compute the sum correctly.

Personally, I prefer to treat the test subject as a single large black box, but there are [good counter arguments](https://vimeo.com/80533536).  Horses for courses.

Comment: Thanks VoiceOfUnreason for you detailes explanation. It has helped me to come to a conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

Constructors can not be mocked (at least with free mocking frameworks).

Write tests without mocking as far as your tests run fast and test case setup is not very very complicated.

In your particular case you should be able to write tests without mocking.

Prepare data

```
var products = new List<Product>
{
    new Product { Quantity = 10, UnitPrice = 5.0m, Offer = "" },
    new Product { Quantity = 2, UnitPrice = 3.0m , Offer = "BuyOneGetOneFree" },
    new Product { Quantity = 3, UnitPrice = 2.0m , Offer = "ThreeInPriceOfTwo" },
}

// prepare expected total
var expected = 57.0m; // 10 * 50.0 + 1 * 3.0 + 2 * 2.0

// Run the test
var actual = CalculateTotalPrice(products);

actual.Should().Be(expected); // pass Ok.
```

With this approach tests will not depend on implementation details.
You will be able to freely play with designs without rewriting tests every time you change your implementation logic.

Comment: Hi Fabio, isn't a good idea to keep **Offer**  out of **Product** and use a collection 
 for mapping product with offer?

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are technically fine, but I would suggest one thing:

```
    if(p.Offer == "")
        calc = new DefaultCalc();
    else if(p.Offer == "BuyOneGetOneFree")
        calc = new BuyOneGetOneFreeCalc();
    else if(p.Offer == "ThreeInPriceOfTwo")
        calc = new ThreeInPriceOfTwoCalc()
```

should **absolutely** go into its own method/scope/whatever.

You are mapping a string to a specific calculator. That should happen in one place, and one place only. You see, first you do that here. Then some method method comes around that needs the same mapping. So you start duplicating.